# How do I turn this function from java to recieve an url to show the results

Tags: java, file, url

So I'm recieving this url http://cei.edu.uy/plata.txt which contains numbers, what my function does is try to give the least amount of money required to get to that number, but I don't know how to actually use the numbers in that url on my function and save the result in the file "result.txt", because as of now I'm giving the numbers mannualy with the var "V" I give the amount of money to the function. This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://cei.edu.uy/plata.txt");
            try (Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream())) {
                File f = new File("result.txt");
                try (PrintStream print = new PrintStream(f)) {
                    int bills[] = {2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100,50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
                    int m = bills.length;
                    int V = 153;
                    System.out.println ( minBills(bills, m, V));

                    while (s.hasNext()) {

                    }
                    print.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        }
    }

    static int minBills(int bills[], int m, int V)
    {

        int table[] = new int[V + 1];

        table[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
            table[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                if (bills[j] <= i)
                {
                    int sub = table[i - bills[j]];
                    if (sub != Integer.MAX_VALUE
                            && sub + 1 < table[i])
                        table[i] = sub + 1;
                }
        }

        if(table[V]==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            return -1;

        return table[V];

    }
}
```

Comment: That URL provides plain text, so you should be able to use your `Scanner` as though you were reading the numbers from the keyboard.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: I'm new to java, and I don't know how to really change what I've got and instead of the "v" var use the scanner and then print the result in the .txt

Comment: Do you know how to read the next integer from a Scanner? If not, read a Scanner tutorial and try to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the numbers form the URL using `InputStreamReader` as below

```
     private static List<Integer> getNumbersFromUrl(String string) {
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL link = new URL(string);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                nums.add(Integer.parseInt(inputLine));
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Passing URL string to  above method

```
        List<Integer> nums = getNumbersFromUrl("http://cei.edu.uy/plata.txt");
        System.out.println("numbers:"+nums);
```

Output:

```
number:[8, 153, 10, 312]
```

**EDIT**

you can get the numbers from URL by calling getNumbersFromUrl method

and to assign 153 reading from URL, replace below line

```
int V = 153;
```

with

```
List<Integer> nums = getNumbersFromUrl("http://cei.edu.uy/plata.txt");
int v = nums.get(1);
```

Note: variable name should start with lowercase(camelCase)

Comment: What I want to do is use the numbers from the url In my function and output a file with the results of my function